# Previous fields text disappears when adding new one with select2 ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was using select2 plugin on my input box to search items from the database using AJAX based on what the user type on it. It was working fine, I can search Items on it and select it when its available, but my problem is whenever I add new rows on my table the previous item fields "text" will be gone, I'm  making a table where you can add/remove rows dynamically so here is my HTML:

```
<td><input name='product[0][name]' class='form-control col-lg-5 itemSearch' type='text' placeholder='select item' /></td>
```

and my javascript:

```
function addRow(){
var toBeAdded = document.getElementById('toBeAdded').value;
if (toBeAdded=='')
    { toBeAdded = 2; }
else if(toBeAdded>10)
{
  toBeAdded = 10;
}

  for (var i = 0; i < toBeAdded; i++) {
    var rowToInsert = '';

     rowToInsert = "<tr><td><input name='product["+rowArrayId+"][name]' class='form-control col-lg-5 itemSearch' type='text' placeholder='select item' /></td>";
    $("#tblItemList tbody").append(
        rowToInsert+
        "<td><textarea readonly name='product["+rowArrayId+"][description]' class='form-control description' rows='1' ></textarea></td>"+
        "<input type='hidden' name='product[" + rowArrayId + "][itemId]' id='itemId'>"+
        "<td><input type='number' min='1' max='9999' name='product["+rowArrayId+"][quantity]' class='qty form-control' required />"+
        "<input id='poItemId' type='hidden' name='product[" + rowArrayId + "][poContentId]'></td>"+
        "<td><input type='number' min='1' step='any' max='9999' name='product["+rowArrayId+"][price]' class='price form-control' required /></td>"+
        "<td class='subtotal'><center><h3>0.00</h3></center></td>"+
        "<input type='hidden' name='product["+rowArrayId+"][delete]' class='hidden-deleted-id'>"+
        "<td class='actions'><a href='#' class='btnRemoveRow btn btn-danger'>x</a></td>"+
        "</tr>");

        rowArrayId = rowArrayId + 1;
     };


 $(".itemSearch").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a product',
    formatResult: productFormatResult,
    formatSelection: productFormatSelection,
    dropdownClass: 'bigdrop',
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
    minimumInputLength:1,
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/productSearch',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                q: term
            };  
        },  
        results: function(data, page) {
            return {results:data};
        }   
    }   
});


function productFormatResult(product) {
var html = "<table><tr>";
 html += "<td>";
html += product.itemName ;
html += "</td></tr></table>";
return html;
}

  function productFormatSelection(product) {
  var selected = "<input type='hidden' name='itemId' value='"+product.id+"'/>";
  return selected + product.itemName;
 }

 $(".qty, .price").bind("keyup change", calculate);
 };
```

here are some screenshots:

1st state:
[image: original state]

2nd state: when searching item on the input box
[image: when adding]

3rd state: after adding new row on my table
[image: after adding new row]

What can be the issue?

Comment: The same id value is used for the input elements as you add rows, maybe this is causing it. If not, it is something you better look at since id values should be unique within page.

Comment: Yeah @melc maybe it was causing the problem, thank you for sharing your thought, Ill give it a try. :)

Comment: Thank you @melc it was the same Id that was causing the the issue, I tried adding a dynamic id on the element Im adding then used it as a selector on my select2 and It was working fine now! thank you very much! :D

Comment: Hi @melvnberd can you post your updated code? I am having the same trouble but some of what I have tried is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same id value is used for the input elements as rows get added.

It is best to have unique id within the page.

Comment: actually I was using class as my selector on the above code. :) so now I changed it to a unique ID! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that every time you call .select2(), that all the selects get reset to the original state. You could only call the constructor on the new box by limiting the scope.

To update only the new select2s you should change the following.
See this example (untested, please adjust):

```
var newHtml = $("<h1>Code to be appended here</h1>");
newHtml.appendTo('#tblItemList tbody');
$('.itemSearch', newHtml).select2(/* ... */)
```

As an alternative you could try "freezing" the state by applying the "selected" attribute to all boxes before you call the constructor.

See this example (untested, please adjust)

```
$('.itemSearch').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).find('option[value='+val+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this @Dragony I was using an input type="text" on this one because its not allowed to use ajax method with <select> element ._.

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that. But I guess the second option is your best bet then. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: I already made it working now, by adding a unique id on the element that Im adding, and used the Id that was generated as a selector for the select2 and it fixed the issue. :) Im not really sure if its the best way to do. Anyways Thank you for your suggestions and efforts! It really helped me too..