# jQuery Select2 does not appear after append in table TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to append a Select2 input box in a column of a table. It is working fine on the first row as it was static in the HTML. Then when I clicked a button to append another row, the select2 wont appear.

The code in the html and the js should be identical for the table part, but I dont know what could be the possible cause.

Here is the screenshot, ignore the UI inconsistencies, I still have more problems in that page but thats another matter.

[image]

Here is the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/unmuk4km/2/

HTML

```
                                <table class="table table-hover" id="tab_owner">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="text-center" colspan="4"><a
                                                class="btn green add-owner pull-left"><i
                                                class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New Owner</a></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                <th> Matrik No. </th>
                                                <th> IC No.</th>
                                                <th> Birth Place</th>
                                                <th> Faculty</th>
                                                <th> Study Year</th>
                                                <th> Phone No.</th>
                                                <th> Email</th>
                                                <th> Year Start Business</th>
                                                <th width="3%"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr id="owner_0">
                                            <td width='15%'><input name="matrik_number" type="text" class="form-control select2"></td>
                                            <td width='10%'><input name="ic_0" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td>
                                            <td width='8%'><input name="bp_0" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td>
                                            <td width='5%'><input name="fac_0" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td>
                                            <td width='5%'><input name="syear_0" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td>
                                            <td width='8%'><input name="student_phoneno_0" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                            <td width='10%'><input name="student_emailadd_0" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                            <td width='3%'><select name="business_yearstart_0" class="form-control required">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>

                                            <td width='3%'><!-- placeholder for remove button --></td>   
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

JS

```
tab_owner.on('click', '.add-owner', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var iRow = $('tbody tr:last',tab_owner).index() + 1;
            var show_studentdata = $("<tr id='owner_"+ iRow +"' >\n" +
                        "<td width='15%'><input name='matrik_number_"+ iRow +"' type='text' class='form-control'></td>\n" +
                        "<td width='10%'><input name='ic_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
                        "<td width='8%'><input name='bp_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
                        "<td width='5%'><input name='fac_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
                        "<td width='5%'><input name='syear_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
                        "<td width='8%'><input name='student_phoneno_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control'></td>\n" +
                        "<td width='10%'><input name='student_emailadd_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control'></td>\n" +
                        "<td width='3%'><select name='business_yearstart_"+ iRow +"'></select></td>\n" +
                        "<td width='3%'><a class='btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm red del-owner pull-right'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i>Remove</a></td>" +
                        "</tr>\n");



            //insert modal data to tables/forms
            $('tbody',tab_owner).append(show_studentdata);

            Metronic.scrollTo(show_studentdata, slideOffeset);

        });

        function loadStudentDetails(d){
            $('[name^=ic_'+ iRow +']').val(d.smIcNo);
            $('[name^=bp_'+ iRow +']').val(d.smBirthPlace);
            $('[name^=fac_'+ iRow +']').val(d.smFacultyCode);
            $('[name^=syear_'+ iRow +']').val(d.studyyear);
            student_phoneno.val(d.smHandphoneNo);
            student_emailadd.val(d.smEmailAddr);
            }

        matrik_number
        .select2({
            allowClear: true,
            placeholder: "Filter as you type",
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                url: 'home/umkei/info/student',
                dataType: 'json',
                quietMillis: 250,
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return { q: term };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        })
        .on("change", function(e) {
            var id = matrik_number.val();

            if(id != ''){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'home/umkei/info/student/'+id,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        showMetronicLoading(el,msgLoading);
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        Metronic.unblockUI(el);


showMetronicAlert('danger','warning',msgInternetError + '. Failed to load Student Info.');
                    },
                    success: function(res){
                        Metronic.unblockUI(el);

                        loadStudentDetails(res);

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The fiddle is not working as I never use this before, but I got some errors in the log but I dont know whats wrong so I apologise for that.

But you should get some ideas on how my codes look like. I have been changing and testing stuff here and there so excuse me if some codes looks inconsistent cuz I must have missed it while putting it in the fiddle.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to initialize the new select2's after you append them.

wrap your select2 initialize code in a function and call it, using *starts with* `name`.

```js
tab_owner.on('click', '.add-owner', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var iRow = $('tbody tr:last', tab_owner).index() + 1;
  var show_studentdata = $("<tr id='owner_" + iRow + "' >\n" +
    "<td width='15%'><input name='matrik_number_" + iRow + "' type='text' class='form-control'></td>\n" +
    "<td width='10%'><input name='ic_" + iRow + "' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
    "<td width='8%'><input name='bp_" + iRow + "' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
    "<td width='5%'><input name='fac_" + iRow + "' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
    "<td width='5%'><input name='syear_" + iRow + "' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
    "<td width='8%'><input name='student_phoneno_" + iRow + "' class='form-control'></td>\n" +
    "<td width='10%'><input name='student_emailadd_" + iRow + "' class='form-control'></td>\n" +
    "<td width='3%'><select name='business_yearstart_" + iRow + "'></select></td>\n" +
    "<td width='3%'><a class='btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm red del-owner pull-right'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i>Remove</a></td>" +
    "</tr>\n");

  //insert modal data to tables/forms
  $('tbody', tab_owner).append(show_studentdata);

  renderSelect2(); // call to render select2

  Metronic.scrollTo(show_studentdata, slideOffeset);

});

function loadStudentDetails(d) {
  $('[name^=ic_' + iRow + ']').val(d.smIcNo);
  $('[name^=bp_' + iRow + ']').val(d.smBirthPlace);
  $('[name^=fac_' + iRow + ']').val(d.smFacultyCode);
  $('[name^=syear_' + iRow + ']').val(d.studyyear);
  student_phoneno.val(d.smHandphoneNo);
  student_emailadd.val(d.smEmailAddr);
}

function renderSelect2() {

  $('[name^="matrik_number"]')
    .select2({
      allowClear: true,
      placeholder: "Filter as you type",
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      ajax: {
        url: 'home/umkei/info/student',
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function(term, page) {
          return {
            q: term
          };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
          return {
            results: data
          };
        },
        cache: true
      }
    })
    .on("change", function(e) {
      var id = matrik_number.val();

      if (id != '') {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'home/umkei/info/student/' + id,
          dataType: 'json',
          beforeSend: function() {
            showMetronicLoading(el, msgLoading);
          },
          error: function() {
            Metronic.unblockUI(el);


            showMetronicAlert('danger', 'warning', msgInternetError + '. Failed to load Student Info.');
          },
          success: function(res) {
            Metronic.unblockUI(el);

            loadStudentDetails(res);

          }
        });
      }
    });
}

renderSelect2();
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/unmuk4km/3/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I tried creating the function before but I guess I didnt know how to call it back so I removed it. It was sooo straight forward. Btw, I have more or less an issue that is almost like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935066/previous-fields-text-disappears-when-adding-new-one-with-select2-ajax

Can you help me with this or do i need to create a new question?

I have an idea on how to do but whatever i tried is not working.

Get the id of the 'tr' or each 'td'(i'm not sure which one is better), and set the selector to match the iRow values that was declared before??

Comment: it would be best to create a new question with an example/demo. glad I could help.