# Select2 jquery values disappear after append, and populate the whole row with unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using select2 with ajax to populate a row in a table. It is working fine.

one row is fine - [image]

I have 2 questions as per below.

1)  I have issues when appending a new row, where the select2 values(of the previous rows/first row) disappears.

[image]

2) The whole table input values will be overwritten/duplicate from the values searched on any of the Select2 fields.

[image]

Here is what I tried/imagine(or some ideas i think what I should do) but I am not sure how to achieve it.

First, here is the HTML code.

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="tab_owner">
   <thead>
       <tr>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="4"><a
       class="btn green add-owner pull-left"><i
       class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New Owner</a></th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th> Matrik No. </th>
           <th> IC No.</th>
           <th> Birth Place</th>
           <th> Faculty</th>
           <th> Study Year</th>
           <th> Phone No.</th>
           <th> Email</th>
           <th> Year Start Business</th>
           <th width="3%"></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr id="owner_0">
          <td width='15%'><input name="matrik_number" type="text" class="form-control select2"></td>
          <td width='10%'><input name="ic_0" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td>
          <td width='8%'><input name="bp_0" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td>
          <td width='5%'><input name="fac_0" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td>
          <td width='5%'><input name="syear_0" type="text" class="form-control" readonly></td>
          <td width='8%'><input name="student_phoneno_0" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
          <td width='10%'><input name="student_emailadd_0" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
          <td width='3%'><select name="business_yearstart_0" class="form-control required">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
                       </select>
         </td>

         <td width='3%'><!-- placeholder for remove button --></td>   
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

1) I need to assign the unique id to the `<tr>` or `<td>`, but how do i call it back?

below is the JS code the append part.

```
  var tab_owner = $('#tab_owner')
  tab_owner.on('click', '.add-owner', function (){

        var iRow = $('tbody tr:last',tab_owner).index() + 1;
        var show_studentdata = $("<tr id='owner_"+ iRow +"' >\n" +
                    "<td width='15%'><input name='matrik_number_"+ iRow +"' type='text' class='form-control'></td>\n" +
                    "<td width='10%'><input name='ic_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
                    "<td width='8%'><input name='bp_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
                    "<td width='5%'><input name='fac_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
                    "<td width='5%'><input name='syear_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control' readonly></td>\n" +
                    "<td width='8%'><input name='student_phoneno_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control'></td>\n" +
                    "<td width='10%'><input name='student_emailadd_"+ iRow +"' class='form-control'></td>\n" +
                    "<td width='3%'><select name='business_yearstart_"+ iRow +"'></select></td>\n" +
                    "<td width='3%'><a class='btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm red del-owner pull-right'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i>Remove</a></td>" +
                    "</tr>\n");

        $('tbody',tab_owner).append(show_studentdata);


    });
```

2) I think this one is almost the same as above, except it inserts from the database, using ajax based on select2 input.

Below is JS code,

```
    var matrik_number = $('[name^=matrik_number]');

    matrik_number
    .select2({
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: "Filter as you type",
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            url: 'home/umkei/info/student',
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 250,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return { q: term };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return { results: data };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    })
    .on("change", function(e) {
        var id = matrik_number.val();

        if(id != ''){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'home/umkei/info/student/'+id,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend:function(){
                    showMetronicLoading(el,msgLoading);
                },
                error: function(){

                },
                success: function(res){

                    loadStudentDetails(res);

                }
            });
        }
    });

    function loadStudentDetails(d){
        $('[name^=ic_]').val(d.smIcNo);
        $('[name^=bp_']').val(d.smBirthPlace);
        $('[name^=fac_]').val(d.smFacultyCode);
        $('[name^=syear_]').val(d.studyyear);
        student_phoneno.val(d.smHandphoneNo);
        student_emailadd.val(d.smEmailAddr);
        }
```

I guess what I really want to know is, do I call/assign unique value id's to the `<tr>` OR the `<td>`? Plus, I am not so sure on how to make the input field calls them back.

I tried something like,

```
trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

but always got the undefined message in the console.

I really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are assigning an id to each of the appending table rows. Is that the id you are trying to select?

Comment: Where are you using the trid = $(this).closest('input').attr('id');  code? Is it inside an on click event for example?

Comment: @LarryLane Yeah I assign them incrementally to each of the appending row, and kept the html with default id of '0'. I am not sure if that is required or not. Should I only assign an id to the <tr> only? or the select2 input?

Comment: @LarryLane I put that code in the on click event, but I dont think thats the right place? I wanted to try to put it in the select2 code, but I am not sure where. Cuz everywhere I put, I got an undefined msg. anyway i edited the code. it should be 'tr' instead of 'input'

Comment: Ok what are you tring to do exactly once you select the id of the row?

Comment: @LarryLane First, I want each of the select2 field to have their own id, to get rid of the disappearing values upon append(I guess thats how to solve the disappearing issue right?) as i read here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935066/previous-fields-text-disappears-when-adding-new-one-with-select2-ajax

Second, I want to autopopulate all those other fields based on the select2 selection in each row, to avoid it populating all fields.

Comment: I am trying to set up a live example to test. Where is your select element that you shown in your screen shot(in the first column)?

Comment: @LarryLane It is the one called matrik_number or $('[name^=matrik_number]')

Comment: There are some errors going on in your code that I will not be able to sort out without additional information. I do not have access to your json to fully test out your script.  One noticeable error that could be causing your blanked out entries is this line $('[name^=bp_']').val(d.smBirthPlace); .  I would start there,the correct code should look like this $('[name^=bp_]').val(d.smBirthPlace); You can right click on the page and click developer tools. The console tab will display errors that on your page. You will have to click F5 to with the console open to check for error on load.